# Meteor 0.8 Blaze: adding a reactive template to the DOM?

Tags: mongodb, templates, meteor, handlebars.js

In my app I need to display an unordered list rendered from a meteor template, and each list item needs to be able to show a sublist rendered from the same template if clicked, and newly added lists will need to be able to optionally further show new sublists.

The original list, and the sublists are represented in Mongo like this:

```
{ person:"Tom", friendIds: [ id1, id2, id3] }
```

I need the sub list items to be reactive so if the sub list items data in the parent Mongo document is modified then the sublist displays the change.

I have tried to use

```
UI.insert(UI.renderWithData(...))
```

which works great on the initial insert, but is not reactive. I've also tried a few other patterns I have found in forums, but none work for me so far.

What is the currently recommended way to approach this problem in 0.8 and beyond? I am planning to delve into the mechanism of Deps to try to get it to work, but I worry if I roll my own solution to this I'll be deviating from the Meteor way.

Comment: Imperative DOM manipulation is generally the wrong approach in Meteor. You should be able to make this work just with declarative templates. In the Session, you could store which sub-lists are expanded, and then in the template for a list item, decide whether or not to display its sub-list depending on the Session variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is a repost of https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/zUG9EVo3rpQ.

I don't see any reason to use the `UI.insert` API here. You should just do it in a normal template:

```
{{#each list}}
  <span>Name: {{person}}</span>

  {{#if expanded}}
    {{#each friendIds}}
      {{> someOtherTemplate}}
    {{/each}}
  {{else}}
    <a class="expand">Show friends</a>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

With helpers like this:

```
Template.foo.expanded = function() { return Session.equals("openedList", this._id); }

Template.foo.events({
  "click .expand": function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Session.set("openedList", this._id);
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try! Dumb Meteor question: could you instead add the Template.foo.expanded function using Template.foo.helpers()? I'm not clear on the difference between adding helpers and adding functions directly to the template object.

Comment: @user800268 Yep, same thing.